# Why is my Ansible playbook using dnf even when yum is explicitly specified?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, package-managers, ansible-facts

I am trying to run a playbook in a Python3 venv that should install a package using yum. I have explicitly specified the ansible_python_interpretor to be used as python2. However, during playbook run, I am observing that it is attempting to do the install using dnf and failing.
How can I successfully get this playbook to run ? I did read [here](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/56583) about a workaround that overrides the ansible_fact for pkg_mgr - but, attempting to set this using 'set_fact' module at the top of my playbook did not work, resulting in a different but similar, error.

Please see details of system, environment, code and execution details below. Any pointers would be of immense help! Thank you.

```
(python3) [root@TestVM-01 esxi-automation]# hostnamectl
   Static hostname: TestVM-01
         Icon name: computer-vm
           Chassis: vm
        Machine ID: xxxx
           Boot ID: xxxx
    Virtualization: vmware
  Operating System: AlmaLinux 8.7 (Stone Smilodon)
       CPE OS Name: cpe:/o:almalinux:almalinux:8::baseos
            Kernel: Linux 4.18.0-425.3.1.el8.x86_64
      Architecture: x86-64
      
(python3) [root@TestVM-01 esxi-automation]# ansible --version
ansible 2.10.17
  config file = /root/esxi-automation/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/root/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /root/.venv/python3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /root/.venv/python3/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.9.13 (main, Nov 16 2022, 10:51:39) [GCC 8.5.0 20210514 (Red Hat 8.5.0-15)]
```

`vcsa-deploy.yml`

```yaml
---
- name: Prepare vcsa installation
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  connection: local
  pre_tasks:
    - name: Install 7z
      yum:
        name:
          - p7zip
          - p7zip-plugins
        state: latest
      vars:
        ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/bin/python2
```

```
(python3) [root@TestVM-01 esxi-automation]# python2 --version
Python 2.7.18

(python3) [root@TestVM-01 esxi-automation]# ansible-playbook vcsa-deploy.yml
[WARNING]: Invalid characters were found in group names but not replaced, use -vvvv to see details

PLAY [Prepare vcsa installation] *****************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Install 7z] ********************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"ansible_facts": {"pkg_mgr": "dnf"}, "changed": false, "cmd": "dnf install -y python2-dnf", "msg": "Could not import the dnf python module using /usr/bin/python2 (2.7.18 (default, Oct 18 2022, 11:09:45) [GCC 8.5.0 20210514 (Red Hat 8.5.0-15)]). Please install `python2-dnf` package or ensure you have specified the correct ansible_python_interpreter.", "rc": 1, "results": [], "stderr": "Error: Unable to find a match: python2-dnf\n", "stderr_lines": ["Error: Unable to find a match: python2-dnf"], "stdout": "Last metadata expiration check: 22:06:19 ago on Thu 09 Mar 2023 06:29:57 AM PST.\nNo match for argument: python2-dnf\n", "stdout_lines": ["Last metadata expiration check: 22:06:19 ago on Thu 09 Mar 2023 06:29:57 AM PST.", "No match for argument: python2-dnf"]}

PLAY RECAP ***************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Edit 1: Additional execution details after making suggested code change.

```html
(python3) [root@TestVM-01 esxi-automation]# ansible-playbook vcsa-deploy.yml -vvv

ansible-playbook 2.10.17
  config file = /root/esxi-automation/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/root/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /root/.venv/python3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /root/.venv/python3/bin/ansible-playbook
  python version = 3.9.13 (main, Nov 16 2022, 10:51:39) [GCC 8.5.0 20210514 (Red Hat 8.5.0-15)]
Using /root/esxi-automation/ansible.cfg as config file
host_list declined parsing /etc/ansible/hosts as it did not pass its verify_file() method
script declined parsing /etc/ansible/hosts as it did not pass its verify_file() method
auto declined parsing /etc/ansible/hosts as it did not pass its verify_file() method
[WARNING]: Invalid characters were found in group names but not replaced, use -vvvv to see details
Parsed /etc/ansible/hosts inventory source with ini plugin
Skipping callback 'default', as we already have a stdout callback.
Skipping callback 'minimal', as we already have a stdout callback.
Skipping callback 'oneline', as we already have a stdout callback.

PLAYBOOK: vcsa-deploy.yml ************************************************************************************************************************************
4 plays in vcsa-deploy.yml

PLAY [Prepare vcsa installation] *****************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Install 7z] ********************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /root/esxi-automation/vcsa-deploy.yml:13
<127.0.0.1> ESTABLISH LOCAL CONNECTION FOR USER: root
<127.0.0.1> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'echo ~root && sleep 0'
<127.0.0.1> EXEC /bin/sh -c '( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo /root/.ansible/tmp `"&& mkdir "` echo /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1678472697.969434-2788-380021
99183395 `" && echo ansible-tmp-1678472697.969434-2788-38002199183395="` echo /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1678472697.969434-2788-38002199183395 `" ) && sle
ep 0'
Using module file /root/.venv/python3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ansible/modules/yum.py
<127.0.0.1> PUT /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-27798uxq16at/tmp10axu51q TO /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1678472697.969434-2788-38002199183395/AnsiballZ_yu
m.py
<127.0.0.1> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'chmod u+x /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1678472697.969434-2788-38002199183395/ /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1678472697.969434-
2788-38002199183395/AnsiballZ_yum.py && sleep 0'
<127.0.0.1> EXEC /bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/python2 /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1678472697.969434-2788-38002199183395/AnsiballZ_yum.py && sleep 0'
<127.0.0.1> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'rm -f -r /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1678472697.969434-2788-38002199183395/ > /dev/null 2>&1 && sleep 0'
The full traceback is:
WARNING: The below traceback may *not* be related to the actual failure.
  File "/tmp/ansible_ansible.legacy.yum_payload_K2tQ9G/ansible_ansible.legacy.yum_payload.zip/ansible/modules/yum.py", line 371, in <module>
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "allow_downgrade": false,
            "autoremove": false,
            "bugfix": false,
            "conf_file": null,
            "disable_excludes": null,
            "disable_gpg_check": false,
            "disable_plugin": [],
            "disablerepo": [],
            "download_dir": null,
            "download_only": false,
            "enable_plugin": [],
            "enablerepo": [],
            "exclude": [],
            "install_repoquery": true,
            "install_weak_deps": true,
            "installroot": "/",
            "list": null,
            "lock_timeout": 30,
            "name": [
                "p7zip",
                "p7zip-plugins"
            ],
            "releasever": null,
            "security": false,
            "skip_broken": false,
            "state": "latest",
            "update_cache": false,
            "update_only": false,
            "use_backend": "auto",
            "validate_certs": true
        }
    },
    "msg": "The Python 2 bindings for rpm are needed for this module. If you require Python 3 support use the `dnf` Ansible module instead.. The Python 2 yum 
module is needed for this module. If you require Python 3 support use the `dnf` Ansible module instead."
}

PLAY RECAP ***************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   

(python3) [root@TestVM-01 esxi-automation]# yum --version
4.7.0
  Installed: dnf-0:4.7.0-11.el8.alma.noarch at Thu 26 Jan 2023 04:29:12 PM GMT
  Built    : AlmaLinux Packaging Team <packager@almalinux.org> at Wed 12 Oct 2022 09:46:34 AM GMT

  Installed: rpm-0:4.14.3-24.el8_7.x86_64 at Fri 03 Feb 2023 01:10:22 AM GMT
  Built    : AlmaLinux Packaging Team <packager@almalinux.org> at Wed 09 Nov 2022 03:50:55 PM GMT
(python3) [root@TestVM-01 esxi-automation]#
```

Comment: I already fixed your code blocks in your first question version. Please use correct formating for your edit.You are not pasting an html snippet but yaml and command output. You just have to look at how it was fixed to just do the same. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit counter intuitive, but the `yum` module actually supports different backends as explained in the [relevant parameter documention](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/yum_module.html#parameter-use_backend)

By default, the backend is discovered. If both `dnf` and `yum` are available, chances are it detected the first. In that case you need to force the backend (untested):

```yaml
---
- name: Prepare vcsa installation
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  connection: local
  pre_tasks:
    - name: Install 7z
      yum:
        name:
          - p7zip
          - p7zip-plugins
        state: latest
        use_backend: yum  # (might be yum4 depending on your case)
      vars:
        ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/bin/python2
```

Comment: I tried using the above -  adding use_backend: yum. But I am getting the following error.  "msg": "The Python 2 bindings for rpm are needed for this module. If you require Python 3 support use the `dnf` Ansible module instead.. The Python 2 yum 
module is needed for this module. If you require Python 3 support use the `dnf` Ansible module instead."

Comment: Are your sure yum is installed on your dnf aware target system ? `dnf install yum`. Note that this would actually not make much sense as python2 is deprecated and you can use dnf in that case targetting a python3 installation.

Comment: Yes, I do have yum installed on the local controller, which is where the playbook is run. If I do a yum install off the same packages - it runs successfully. I am adding more details to the log contents - please could you check..?

Comment: Why are you not just using DNF?  Also, it's a bit confusing at this point, but you stated in your question that you are using Python3 and that only supports DNF and not yum.

Comment: Even when I'm using dnf, I'm getting the same error but for Python3, unfortunately.